# what is time complexity of the iterative binomial coefficient?

Tags: algorithm

what is time complexity of the iterative binomial coefficient by using dynamic programming?? And how to find it?   and can i say the following code is an example of iterative for binomial coefficient by using dynamic programming?!!

```
class BinomialCoefficient 
{ 
    // Returns value of Binomial Coefficient C(n, k) 
    static int binomialCoeff(int n, int k) 
    { 
        int C[][] = new int[n+1][k+1]; 
        int i, j; 

        // Calculate value of Binomial Coefficient in bottom up manner 
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
        { 
            for (j = 0; j <= min(i, k); j++) 
            { 
                // Base Cases 
                if (j == 0 || j == i) 
                    C[i][j] = 1; 

                // Calculate value using previosly stored values 
                else
                    C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + C[i-1][j]; 
            } 
        } 

        return C[n][k]; 
    } 

    // A utility function to return minimum of two integers 
    static int min(int a, int b) 
    { 
        return (a<b)? a: b; 
    } 

    /* Driver program to test above function*/
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int n = 5, k = 2; 
        System.out.println("Value of C("+n+","+k+") is "+binomialCoeff(n, k)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You fill trapezoidal part of table (Pascal's triangle). Height of trapeze is `k`, long base is `n`, short base is `n-k`.

So it contains `k*(n+(n-k))/2` items, algorithm makes same number of cell operations, and complexity is `O(nk)`